# in-app billing for android application

Tags: android

I want to use Google play store API for my android game application and I am very confused from where I can get this API and implement them.Can anyone please tell me in detail,it will be great help to me as I am new to android gaming.So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Billing Library is a part of the SDK, you only need to download it via the  SDK manager.

Also a nice training class is available at Goole Developers:
https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This official docs are easy enough to follow:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: Thank you Anup Cowkur but I am not able to make Service connection.

Comment: Post your logcat and the exact error message you are receiving

Comment: I fixed that.Is there any dummy public key or something for testing purpose?

Comment: Here's a guide on how to test it: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html